# Remove non printing chars from bash variable

Tags: bash, variables

I have some variable `$a`. This variable have non printing characters (carriage return ^M).

```
>echo $a
some words for compgen
>a+="END"
>echo $a
ENDe words for compgen
```

How I can remove that char? 
I know that `echo "$a"` display it correct. But it's not a solution in my case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To remove just the trailing carriage return from `a`, use

```
a=${a%$'\r'}
```

Answer (score 36):

You could use `tr`:

```
tr -dc '[[:print:]]' <<< "$var"
```

would remove non-printable character from `$var`.

```
$ foo=$'abc\rdef'
$ echo "$foo"
def
$ tr -dc '[[:print:]]' <<< "$foo"
abcdef
$ foo=$(tr -dc '[[:print:]]' <<< "$foo")
$ echo "$foo"
abcdef
```

Comment: *Beware:* This will also remove umlauts and many other actually printable characters.

Comment: With this tweak from https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/linux-unix/how-remove-non-printable-ascii-characters-file-unix I got better results: `tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176'`

Comment: @Chiru, ...that varies depending on your operating system and your current locale. With `LC_CTYPE` set to a character set where umlauts are valid, and an OS providing multibyte-aware tools, they'll survive.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying to send a notification via libnotify, with content that may contain unprintable characters.  The existing solutions did not quite work for me (using a whitelist of characters using `tr` works, but strips any multi-byte characters).

Here is what worked, while passing the  test:

```
message=$(iconv --from-code=UTF-8 -c <<< "$message")
```

Answer (score 3):

As an equivalent to the `tr` approach using only shell builtins:

```
cleanVar=${var//[![:print:]]/}
```

...substituting `:print:` with the character class you want to keep, if appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

```
tr -dc '[[:alpha:]]'
```

will translate your string to only have alpha characters (if that is needed)