# How to translate and remove non-printable characters?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, telnet, non-printing-characters

I know there are a lot of ways to remove non-printable characters in Linux like [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108359/how-to-remove-all-special-characters-in-linux-text) or [tr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22045175/remove-non-printing-chars-from-bash-variable). But I want to remove them as `cat` command print. Here comes my example file which comes from `telnet`:

```
ae23        Enabled     Down    Disabled      Auto    Auto                                                    ^M^@^M
ae24        Enabled     Down    Disabled      Auto    Auto                                                    ^M^@^M
^[[J^M^@ --More-- (END) ^[[J^M^@ --More-- (END) ^[[J^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^[[J^[[J^[[J^M^@test-40.Int> exit
```

There are some extra characters including non-printable and printable like `^[`, `^H`, `^M`, `[J`, `--More-- (END)` and so on. When I use `cat` to print the file, the result shows:

```
ae23        Enabled     Down    Disabled      Auto    Auto
ae24        Enabled     Down    Disabled      Auto    Auto
test.Int> exit
```

That's what I want. However, only use `sed` and `tr` can only remove the non-printable characters except `[J`, `--More-- (END)`.
So how to remove all of them just like the `cat` show? In my point of view, it's a "translation" way but not "remove" way.

Comment: Why are you using `more` in the first place? Just `unset PAGER` in the environment where you are getting these results, or don't pipe to `more` if you are explicitly doing that.

Comment: `colcrt` can remove (some) formatting codes similarly to using `cat` on a file with screen control codes.

Comment: @tripleee `more` is needed, showing the result on one page in not what I want. `cat` is a command can show without non-printable characters. But I want to remove all the extra characters just as the question shows and then pass the remaining string to the next pipeline step.

Comment: No, `cat` displays all the characters in the file completely verbatim, but your terminal interprets them (switching to boldface, backspacing over text, etc) so when it finishes you see what looks like text without terminal control codes.

Comment: How is `more` needed if you eventually intend to pass this to a pipe? Capture the output and pipe it to `more` separately in an interactive session if that's what you want.

Comment: @tripleee it's a user interactive way just like the `telnet` command. The user just wants to display one page at a time.

Comment: @tripleee The question you mentioned https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output works for me. All the `more` characters are removed!

Comment: @tripleee Yes, my fault. This question can be marked duplicate.