# How to remove backspaces in bash?

Tags: r, bash, backspace

I have a .tsv file, bad formatted with backspaces in the middle "\b". How can I remove them with bash?

I have tried with sed 's/\b//g', but no result obtained.
Then, I tried to import it into R and I tried to remove them with gsub, but no result too.

Attached, in the pic, you can see the import output.

[image]

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22045175/remove-non-printing-chars-from-bash-variable) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34412754/trying-to-remove-non-printable-characters-junk-values-from-a-unix-file)?

Comment: can you post the output of `IFS='' read -r firstline < file.tsv; printf '%q\n' "$firstline"` ?